# chi-square goodness of fit test on count data

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, count-data

I am performing chi-square goodness-of-fit test on a predicted and observed count data. Some observed counts are very low or zero.
I have a two part question,

**- Does r's chisq.test function exclude columns from g-o-f test based on observed count?**
**- If it does not, what criteria should I use to exclude low count columns.**

The data is just a sample of a multi-gb dataset to make the point. Please do not attempt a chisq-test on this data set since the count(obs) is not equal to count(pred).

```
structure(list(motif = c("ATX", "BTX", "BQX", "BAX", "VTX", "STX", 
                         "IQX", "DTX", "BZX", "AQX", "DZX", "ETX", "AAX", "BPX", "ITX", 
                         "BRX", "EQX", "VQX", "EZX", "NTX", "LTX", "ERX", "BVX", "LQX", 
                         "EBX", "ZDX", "ADX", "BEX", "TTX", "ABX", "DBX", "BIX", "TSX", 
                         "AZX", "DQX", "TBX", "LBX", "BSX", "SQX", "EAX", "BMX", "VAX", 
                         "AVX", "TDX", "DRX", "VBX", "TNX", "NBX", "ANX", "IBX", "RDX", 
                         "QBX", "VDX", "QQX", "SAX", "DAX", "QDX", "TAX", "AIX", "ASX", 
                         "LZX", "ARX", "ZBX", "LAX", "SVX", "SBX", "TQX", "DIX", "EDX", 
                         "SSX", "LRX", "EIX", "IDX", "IAX", "QNX", "SDX", "HQX", "LDX", 
                         "DVX", "VZX", "QZX", "QTX", "ZNX", "SIX", "SNX", "ZQX", "SZX", 
                         "EVX", "DDX", "SRX", "NAX", "QRX", "RBX", "QAX", "FTX", "INX", 
                         "LSX", "AEX", "HBX", "NDX", "BDX", "VSX", "NNX", "ZAX", "NQX", 
                         "LVX", "LNX", "AMX", "RQX", "FQX", "ENX", "ZTX", "EMX", "VNX", 
                         "HHX", "SHX", "QHX", "MTX", "FBX", "MQX", "FSX", "MSX", "YTX", 
                         "DNX", "IZX", "RTX", "CBX", "ESX", "LIX", "BLX", "DSX", "ALX", 
                         "ZRX", "VIX", "LEX", "RRX", "VVX", "ZZX", "NSX", "EEX", "ISX", 
                         "SEX", "NZX", "VRX", "IRX", "TZX", "SLX", "MBX", "VEX", "TVX", 
                         "DEX", "RNX", "IHX", "QVX", "TRX", "TIX", "YBX", "DMX", "RVX", 
                         "QYX", "BNX", "RSX", "HDX", "QSX", "RAX", "ZEX", "LLX", "DLX", 
                         "NVX", "TEX", "QMX", "YQX", "IVX", "SMX", "LMX", "MZX", "MDX", 
                         "FAX", "ELX", "NEX", "HTX", "MAX", "BHX", "IEX", "ZSX", "VMX", 
                         "FVX", "CSX", "NIX", "IIX", "MNX", "MEX", "CTX", "REX", "FDX", 
                         "EHX", "QEX", "HRX", "FLX", "RZX", "QIX", "DHX", "ZVX", "ZIX", 
                         "BCX", "HEX", "NRX", "FRX", "HNX", "VLX", "THX", "AHX", "YSX", 
                         "SFX", "CQX", "HSX", "YAX", "TMX", "YDX", "YRX", "FIX", "MRX", 
                         "HZX", "ZCX", "QLX", "ECX", "RLX", "LHX", "YVX", "NMX", "ZLX", 
                         "RMX", "RIX", "TLX", "MMX", "CEX", "HAX", "SYX", "YEX", "ZMX", 
                         "NHX", "QFX", "FZX", "IMX", "MVX", "FNX", "BYX", "CRX", "WRX", 
                         "WBX", "CZX", "BFX", "LFX", "FEX", "RCX", "AYX", "NLX", "CAX", 
                         "BWX", "AFX", "YNX", "RHX", "YZX", "SWX", "ZHX", "FFX", "CVX", 
                         "WSX", "FHX", "MHX", "NWX", "ILX", "WZX", "SCX", "AWX", "WTX", 
                         "RYX", "CIX", "ZFX", "CDX", "WAX", "VCX", "WHX", "TYX", "TFX", 
                         "FMX", "ACX", "NYX", "HVX", "WVX", "VHX", "TCX", "RWX", "MIX", 
                         "HMX", "DFX", "WDX", "IFX", "HIX", "CMX", "YIX", "NFX", "MLX", 
                         "LYX", "LCX", "EFX", "DYX", "YMX", "YLX", "WNX", "VYX", "VWX", 
                         "EYX", "CCX", "CLX", "WLX", "RFX", "HCX", "YHX", "WEX", "VFX", 
                         "MFX", "HYX", "CNX", "YYX", "QCX", "NCX", "HLX", "HFX", "DWX", 
                         "DCX", "YCX", "WWX", "WQX", "QWX", "LWX", "IWX", "ICX", "FWX", 
                         "FCX", "EWX", "CFX", "YFX", "WYX", "WMX", "WCX", "TWX", "MYX", 
                         "MWX", "BWX", "IYX", "HWX", "CYX", "CHX", "CWX", "FYX", "ZYX", 
                         "MCX", "WFX", "WIX", "YWX"), obs = c(82015L, 51601L, 41922L, 
                                                              25545L, 15795L, 14810L, 13259L, 13210L, 12210L, 11994L, 8820L, 
                                                              8745L, 7791L, 7275L, 7084L, 7031L, 6726L, 6654L, 6438L, 6198L, 
                                                              6133L, 6096L, 5916L, 5916L, 5704L, 5656L, 5250L, 5249L, 5244L, 
                                                              5201L, 4616L, 4581L, 4287L, 3862L, 3364L, 3274L, 3012L, 2964L, 
                                                              2820L, 2770L, 2669L, 2478L, 2447L, 2263L, 2250L, 2238L, 2193L, 
                                                              2150L, 2095L, 2037L, 1956L, 1904L, 1836L, 1756L, 1754L, 1754L, 
                                                              1733L, 1705L, 1676L, 1592L, 1579L, 1558L, 1535L, 1492L, 1467L, 
                                                              1467L, 1334L, 1266L, 1166L, 1149L, 1143L, 1117L, 1023L, 963L, 
                                                              960L, 947L, 922L, 910L, 882L, 867L, 862L, 848L, 815L, 809L, 774L, 
                                                              751L, 738L, 738L, 719L, 718L, 718L, 712L, 700L, 700L, 694L, 693L, 
                                                              687L, 684L, 674L, 659L, 653L, 634L, 626L, 599L, 588L, 586L, 579L, 
                                                              570L, 559L, 543L, 531L, 529L, 507L, 475L, 475L, 461L, 452L, 439L, 
                                                              437L, 434L, 423L, 408L, 399L, 397L, 394L, 388L, 387L, 381L, 379L, 
                                                              359L, 356L, 352L, 320L, 315L, 306L, 300L, 297L, 293L, 285L, 284L, 
                                                              283L, 282L, 276L, 274L, 268L, 264L, 264L, 251L, 247L, 244L, 238L, 
                                                              237L, 233L, 230L, 228L, 221L, 220L, 209L, 207L, 199L, 192L, 188L, 
                                                              174L, 166L, 164L, 163L, 153L, 150L, 147L, 146L, 146L, 141L, 139L, 
                                                              136L, 136L, 135L, 132L, 132L, 132L, 130L, 130L, 127L, 126L, 122L, 
                                                              121L, 119L, 109L, 109L, 107L, 104L, 100L, 96L, 95L, 93L, 93L, 
                                                              91L, 90L, 88L, 85L, 84L, 84L, 82L, 80L, 76L, 74L, 72L, 71L, 71L, 
                                                              67L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 63L, 61L, 61L, 58L, 57L, 57L, 
                                                              55L, 55L, 54L, 53L, 53L, 52L, 52L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 49L, 48L, 47L, 
                                                              47L, 47L, 46L, 44L, 43L, 43L, 41L, 39L, 39L, 38L, 37L, 37L, 36L, 
                                                              36L, 34L, 33L, 33L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 31L, 31L, 30L, 30L, 29L, 29L, 
                                                              28L, 28L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 26L, 26L, 23L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 
                                                              21L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 17L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
                                                              15L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 
                                                              10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
                                                              6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                              3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                              1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
               pred = c(48922.334, 64768.4213, 30136.5597, 14757.2433, 12433.5807, 
                        11054.1222, 4772.4329, 14739.983, 11177.679, 22763.4209, 
                        2543.8137, 15953.7373, 11146.7714, 13026.0731, 10256.7429, 
                        6438.2609, 7423.228, 5785.3093, 2753.2824, 4660.8627, 8886.1271, 
                        1585.8704, 4117.3449, 4134.6893, 3208.5783, 504.1244, 5763.5962, 
                        2516.0881, 8311.7372, 9839.1452, 2964.4709, 3289.8274, 550.0138, 
                        8442.9747, 6858.4716, 1671.6371, 1787.1571, 4285.93, 5143.4512, 
                        3634.9996, 1457.748, 2832.945, 3110.0051, 979.2153, 1465.218, 
                        2500.6126, 419.1209, 937.3818, 2466.9178, 2062.8121, 231.9063, 
                        845.8318, 1464.8144, 1956.88, 2518.6405, 3358.4502, 495.4732, 
                        1893.7983, 2484.9461, 3237.3446, 1533.5602, 4863.0914, 860.6004, 
                        2024.6709, 702.7133, 2223.1792, 3867.4274, 748.6982, 1879.5281, 
                        731.486, 883.3194, 810.3493, 1208.3586, 2336.9606, 212.071, 
                        1302.2988, 503.9337, 1046.8848, 937.0244, 2145.7768, 725.8087, 
                        4205.6568, 215.7739, 561.4797, 557.4062, 1991.048, 1907.711, 
                        1014.1831, 1736.5343, 1098.8275, 1061.9602, 418.0605, 395.8917, 
                        958.2432, 1085.7276, 517.1982, 588.023, 1900.508, 217.8177, 
                        549.1016, 7630.4419, 822.7691, 235.0249, 974.9746, 2168.686, 
                        564.8933, 448.0846, 1101.0988, 915.9179, 505.1859, 804.4702, 
                        4279.0895, 359.072, 626.9656, 11.5135, 117.5142, 44.7095, 
                        888.4974, 218.359, 413.4153, 71.846, 58.7947, 454.0525, 743.2664, 
                        1770.1, 1968.458, 69.1264, 1055.709, 451.3592, 557.1165, 
                        975.391, 420.8137, 425.36, 631.5475, 345.2034, 195.6732, 
                        790.4059, 738.4816, 308.4239, 619.762, 678.7209, 429.4245, 
                        804.3677, 1235.9516, 1019.5646, 1434.4325, 95.0839, 178.6925, 
                        483.0129, 528.3792, 572.6108, 99.2599, 109.0374, 267.3547, 
                        826.2226, 422.1838, 91.318, 331.754, 125.1354, 7.808, 3265.9597, 
                        130.2591, 127.5938, 278.3015, 448.5058, 166.2317, 76.4355, 
                        126.7885, 296.2922, 322.8898, 94.657, 211.2693, 652.0237, 
                        248.796, 200.0008, 153.3361, 104.6749, 247.379, 137.2288, 
                        181.0626, 1083.0364, 202.4408, 688.5404, 398.4483, 283.1608, 
                        279.8436, 69.02, 22.7445, 236.7424, 520.9779, 44.8026, 34.5159, 
                        343.7112, 76.4696, 127.9108, 169.6011, 163.379, 107.6585, 
                        9.3391, 339.7148, 213.6208, 156.6979, 272.0228, 217.3508, 
                        94.2627, 42.0732, 463.3099, 107.926, 54.6123, 106.9495, 88.3605, 
                        520.0838, 30.0461, 16.1911, 159.9278, 71.6679, 103.4542, 
                        187.0729, 53.4924, 45.1348, 55.1481, 88.3205, 186.9095, 6.2277, 
                        36.1757, 23.2188, 16.932, 94.4667, 28.8642, 104.9024, 36.8073, 
                        44.3042, 99.9853, 71.4948, 19.9975, 13.3523, 246.7658, 20.5224, 
                        17.6388, 96.3098, 49.5487, 6.1601, 187.374, 230.8493, 56.482, 
                        54.748, 120.2453, 34.1664, 8.0639, 16.3151, 59.3174, 94.8669, 
                        13.0156, 42.1778, 2.8649, 90.8264, 40.0912, 78.3133, 41.391, 
                        71.657, 22.8957, 20.9263, 78.36, 7.0643, 45.4902, 1.5903, 
                        21.8498, 5.3681, 11.5422, 9.4454, 2.9786, 88.2251, 14, 16.0879, 
                        31.2644, 81.122, 3.6545, 17.4584, 6.2676, 40.493, 18.4833, 
                        18.0956, 0.8624, 15.4311, 12.1743, 24.4366, 71.2006, 8.6531, 
                        68.8489, 5.1569, 132.179, 12.0967, 1.258, 45.1301, 24.376, 
                        21.5898, 9.5571, 15.0231, 55.0114, 7.7359, 23.063, 6.8268, 
                        7.6426, 16.4975, 12.9327, 23.3676, 27.3654, 10.2194, 3.9056, 
                        4.0906, 23.0835, 7.9458, 29.6188, 0.5002, 2.9565, 0.6978, 
                        2.8832, 1.5762, 4.8269, 3.1514, 18.2116, 1.3014, 2.0107, 
                        17.3317, 0.843, 6.1208, 6.7833, 9.3159, 1.5863, 9.4197, 21.4523, 
                        0.6608, 0.0518, 37.7458, 2.6877, 5.6788, 6.5547, 14.9275, 
                        0.6938, 1.5801, 10.1954, 0.5034, 0.6651, 0.1506, 1.8258, 
                        0.1181, 5.3117, 1.6495, 0.5678, 2.7346, 19.0421, 0.6921, 
                        0.6381, 3.6539, 0.2197, 2.0157, 7.9443, 1.2931, 0.1188, 4.1205, 
                        0.2902)), row.names = c(NA, -361L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                      "data.frame"))
```

I first do a chi-square goodness of fit test to test if the observed count of some motifs is significantly more than that predicted by theory. Next, I identify these preferential motifs by plotting deleted studentized residuals vs predicted values using olsrr package.

[image: deleted studentized residuals vs predicted values obtained using olsrr package]

Comment: What R code does: Not a routine R user, and I don't know, but (1) I guess it doesn't exclude any cells for having low observed counts, and (2) in any case, you can make up a toy example to check.  In general: The problems with chi-square arise with low **expected** counts. Zero observed counts are what they are, and the decision to exclude any should be principled and scientific not statistical. The question is knowing for certain that certain zeros are inevitable (structural) and not just sampling variation in counting rare categories.

Comment: @NickCox: The zeros are structural and inevitable as the motifs I am looking for (column 1) are not there. When you say the decision to exclude should be scientific, does this mean chi-square tests generally take into account even zero counts when fitting?

Comment: Zeros are always taken as sampling zeros in my experience, unless you arrange otherwise. Put simply, and I hope not too bluntly, how is the code to know what is impossible? More simply, what is impossible should be omitted. That is easy in a one-way analysis but not otherwise, yet R code probably exists.

Comment: I cannot see any information in this question or the sample data to identify these "structural zeros."  The sample data don't even look like actual data: they appear instead to be a summary output of some kind of series of statistical tests. Also of importance is your probability model for the counts as well as your fitting procedure.  Finally, if you have billions of observations (which I presume is what "multi-gb" is intended to suggest), what are you doing with a hypothesis test, which almost surely would be pointless? Could you elaborate on these points?

Comment: @whuber: I edited the original post with the output of dput. I do not have billions of observations. I have multiple data frames, each with a few hundred observations. The data frames come from analysis of a certain motif present across the clades of kingdom animalia and so on. Null hypotheis is that the pair of characters observed in positions 1 and 2 of the motif are randomly distributed. Chi-square analysis suggests rejecting null hypothesis i.e. there are preferential occurrences of the pairs of characters in positions 1 and 2. Does this make sense?

Comment: I don't really follow, because some of the motifs have the same two-letter prefixes, which indicates there's more going on here than you have yet described.  The problem is that all the values of `Motif` with "W" at either position appear twice (four times for "WWX"), almost always with very different (but nonzero) counts.  The role of `ZrWd` is completely opaque.  If it's not relevant, why post it?  If it is relevant, it's seemingly unrelated to anything you have described. Finally, there's no `pred` present in that data structure, although you refer to it in the text.

Comment: @whuber: Sorry, I used bash substitution to obscure the true motifs due to data sharing restrictions. Clearly, didn't do a good job. I edited the post with hopefully a better attempt. Every motif should now be unique. "Pred" is the third column.

Comment: I'm afraid that's of little help, because essentially the only actionable information you have yet provided is the advice *not* to attempt a chi-squared analysis.  In other words, you offer a heap of artificial data with no real description and no clear objectives.   The only part of your post that could possibly be understood and answered objectively is the one about `R`, where you can establish by testing or consulting its documentation that `chisq.test`  won't exclude anything.

Comment: @whuber: Let me try again. The "obs" column are actual observations of the amino acid sequence of a particular protein family in archae. Now, the questions I am trying to ask are,
-Are there pairs of amino acids excluding the third position, whose total observed count is significantly more than that expected based on theory (the predicted value)? Chi-square goodness of fit test suggests as much. 
-The next step is to identify  preferential motifs. I do a linear regression (obs ~ pred) and plot deleted standardized residuals using package "olsrr" in R. The outliers are labelled in the plot.

Comment: In principle, exactly how those counts are "predicted by theory" will matter for deciding the applicability of the chi-squared test (or any other test).  Some information about that would be helpful.

Comment: @whuber: Predicted = (total count of a given amino acid in position1 in all motifs * total count of a given amino acid in position2) / Total count of all triplets. As an example, if 10% of all amino acids in position1 are B and 2% of all amino acids in position2 are Z, then 0.2% of all motifs are expected to be BZX.

Comment: @whuber: Predicted = (total count of a given amino acid in position1 in all motifs * total count of a given amino acid in position2) / Total count of all triplets. As an example, if 10% of all amino acids in position1 are B and 2% of all amino acids in position2 are Z, then 0.2% of all motifs are expected to be BZX.

Comment: That sounds like a standard chi-squared testing situation.  As @NickCox pointed out, actual counts are irrelevant: only expected counts matter.  Moreover, when there are many cells, it's ok to have quite a few tiny expected counts: the chi-squared distribution is still accurate. But since you have so much data, the test will surely be significant.  So, proceed to examining the highest residuals.

Comment: @whuber: And the approach of first doing a chi-squared test and then identifying the residuals using "deleted studentized residuals" vs "Predicted" plot is correct? Sorry, this is a very new field I am venturing after 20 years in a different field. So, want to be doubly sure before submitting the article.

Comment: The paper by Haberman, S. J. 1973. The analysis of residuals in cross-classified tables. _Biometrics_ 29: 205–220. https://doi.org/10.2307/2529686 has served me well/ In turn, I don't know what precisely are deleted studentized residuals.